# how do i upgrade my sqlite3 package on debian lenny

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Short story:

I need the >3.7.3 build of sqlite3, but I currently have 3.5.?. How can I upgrade the package?

Long story:

Trying to install etherpad-lite (node.js implementation of etherpad). Install fails because of sqlite3 package. I tried to install the npm package of sqlite3... again fails. According to this github issue (https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3/issues/27) it looks as if I need greater than 3.7.3 package. I can't seem to find any docs on how to upgrade the package.

Thanks for any help offered!

Comment: Haha this drived me insane, but finally I solved it. Answer coming soon ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compile you probably need `build-essentials`:

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ apt-cache search ^build-essential$
build-essential - Informational list of build-essential packages
alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Compile SQLite:

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp$ wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070701.tar.gz
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3070701$ ./configure
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3070701$ make
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3070701$ sudo make install
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3070701$ sudo ldconfig
```

especially `sudo ldconfig` is important. When I did not do that I got

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/tmp/sqlite-autoconf-3070701$ sqlite3
SQLite header and source version mismatch
2010-08-23 18:52:01 42537b60566f288167f1b5864a5435986838e3a3
2011-06-28 17:39:05 af0d91adf497f5f36ec3813f04235a6e195a605f
```

I am running [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) which is based on Debian:

alfred@alfred-laptop:~/linux$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=maverick
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.10"

Finally I ran `sqlite3`

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ sqlite3 --version
3.7.7.1 2011-06-28 17:39:05 af0d91adf497f5f36ec3813f04235a6e195a605f
```

Comment: Awesome. Haven't had a chance to try this yet, but will let you know if that fixes my problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: It probably should because Ubuntu is based on Debian.

Comment: Haha that `ldconfig` really bite me in the ass in the beginning ;)

Answer (score 2):

I dont have root access so I installed it like this :
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/h4ck3rm1k3/perl5/lib

here are the details :

vi ~/.bashrc and add  :

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/perl5/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/h4ck3rm1k3/perl5/lib
```

import the new settings

```
. ~/.bashrc

wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3071000.tar.gz
tar -xzf sqlite-autoconf-3071000.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3071000/
./configure --prefix=/home/h4ck3rm1k3/perl5
make PREFIX=/home/h4ck3rm1k3/perl5
make install  PREFIX=/home/h4ck3rm1k3/perl5
sqlite3
```

mike